# Exception in coroutine not shown if enable file logging

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-logging

I minimal my problem as next:

**logger.conf:**

```
###################################
[loggers]
keys=root
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=handlerScreen,handlerFile

###################################
[handlers]
keys=handlerScreen,handlerFile
[handler_handlerScreen]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formScreen
args=(sys.stderr,)
[handler_handlerFile]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=formFile
args=('%(log_file)s', 'a')

###################################
[formatters]
keys=formScreen,formFile
[formatter_formScreen]
format=%(asctime)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
[formatter_formFile]
format=%(asctime)s %(filename)-21s[line:%(lineno)-3d] %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

**fc.py:**

```
import asyncio
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logger.conf", defaults=dict(log_file="run.log"))

async def fun():
    print("1")
    1/0
    print("2")

async def action():
    asyncio.create_task(fun())
    print("do other tasks at once")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

asyncio.run(action())
```

**Execution:**

```
$ python3 fc.py
do other tasks at once
1
```

**Question:**

You could see `1/0` didn't print any error in screen, but as `2` not be print, so I guess the exception already happen, just I can't see anything in screen, why could that happen?

**What I have tried?**

1. Disable file logging:

   ```
   import asyncio
   import logging.config

   # Disable file logging
   # logging.config.fileConfig("logger.conf", defaults=dict(log_file="run.log"))

   async def fun():
       print("1")
       1/0
       print("2")

   async def action():
       asyncio.create_task(fun())
       print("do other tasks at once")
       await asyncio.sleep(5)

   asyncio.run(action())
   ```

   Then it run as next:

   ```
   $ python3 fc.py
   do other tasks at once
   1
   Task exception was never retrieved
   future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<fun() done, defined at fc.py:6> 
   exception=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')>
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "fc.py", line 9, in fun
       1/0
   ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
   ```
2. Add `try...except`:

   ```
   import asyncio
   import logging.config

   logging.config.fileConfig("logger.conf", defaults=dict(log_file="run.log"))

   async def fun():
       print("1")
       try:
           1/0
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)
       print("2")

   async def action():
       asyncio.create_task(fun())
       print("do other tasks at once")
       await asyncio.sleep(5)

   asyncio.run(action())
   ```

   Then, it run as next:

   ```
   $ python3 fc.py
   do other tasks at once
   1
   division by zero
   2
   ```

So, how can I make the error be shown without disable file logging, meanwhile without using explicit `try...catch`? If I could know why my situation happen, that will be better.

NOTE: `await asyncio.create_task(fun())` is not what I need. In my scenario, I can't wait `fun` be finished then do next actions. I use `Python 3.8.10` if that mattered.

Comment: Not sure why you are not defining the `logger` and using the standard `logger.error(message)`. Why don't you want to use `try/except`? You could catch the exception, log it and then re-raise the same exception.

Comment: @VladSiv You mean why I use `print(1)` not `logger`? I do use that in my formal code, just when I minimal my problem, I quickly use `print`.   For `try/except`, this happens when I know it may raise exception. But I think I shouldn't put `try/except` everywhere. I mean in that coroutine, E.g. `if I remove item during dict iterator, there should be error there`, but this is a coding problem, I shouldn't add `try/except` around that. For such unexpected error, I want to see it quickly during coding phase, but currently it will hide the errors which make me can't fix these error in coding phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check the source of `asyncio`, I got the reason: asyncio also use `logging` to print the exception:

**asyncio/log.py:**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)
```

**asyncio/base_events.py:**

```
def default_exception_handler(self, context):
    """Default exception handler.

    This is called when an exception occurs and no exception
    handler is set, and can be called by a custom exception
    handler that wants to defer to the default behavior.

    ......
    """
    ......
    logger.error('\n'.join(log_lines), exc_info=exc_info)
```

So, asyncio define a logger with name "asyncio" (__package__). However, in my `logger.conf`, I just define a logger with `keys=root`, this is the reason the error not be shown to screen.

So, change `logger.conf` to next could work, although I didn't know how to let `logger.conf` default handle all `logger` without explictly specify them:

```
##################################
[loggers]
keys=root,asyncio
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=handlerScreen,handlerFile
[logger_asyncio]
level=DEBUG
qualname=asyncio
handlers=handlerScreen,handlerFile
```